# How to detect when focus is gained in a TextEdit component

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I've searched through the docs to find a signal to hook into when a `TextEdit` component has been focused so that I can do some formatting, but I can't find anything. I have a `TextEdit` component that allows users to edit a number, but prints the number with locale when not focused, like this:

```
TextEdit {
    text: object.number.toLocaleString()
    onFocus: { text = object.number; }
    onEditingFinished: {
        // Validation
        object.number = parseInt(text);
    }
}
```

Is there something  I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?
I used onPropertyChanged to achieve it by creating 2 text edit fields so I can change focus from one to the other. What you will see here is the text change when you click back and forth between `TextEdit`s

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window
{
    id: mainWindow
    width: 800
    height: 800
    visible: true

    TextEdit {
        id: t1
        text: "defaut"    
        onFocusChanged: {
            if(focus)
                text = "focused"
            else
                text = "not focused"
        }
    }

    TextEdit {
        anchors.top: t1.bottom
        text: "default2"    
        onFocusChanged: {
            if(focus)
                text = "focused"
            else
                text = "not focused"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a perfect example of the functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `onFocusChange`, you can also directly bind the `text`value and it will react to focus change: `text: focus ? "focused" : "not focused"`